# Use custom post meta in permalink

Tags: permalinks, pre-get-posts

I have a random alphanumeric ID assigned to each post as a post meta item, and am looking to use that in the permalink.

I've found something that works, but it breaks other posts and pages.

For example this code below works if I go to post `http://mywebsi.te/jfskl93` it shows the post, but if I go to page `http://mywebsi.te/contact` then I get a listing of all posts, no pages and no 404.

I change my permalinks to show `/%custom_id%` then drop this into my functions.php

```
function customsite_pre_post( $query ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || is_admin() )
        return;

    $id = $query->get( 'custom_id' );
    if ( ! empty( $id ) ) {

        global $wpdb;
        $value = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = %s LIMIT 1" , $id ) );
        if ( $value ) {
            $query->set( 'p', $value );
        } else {
            // No match. How do I get make it search other posts and pages?
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customsite_pre_post' );
```

As mentioned, it works for grabbing the post which has the query var in the post meta but anything outside of that is broken.

What I'm trying to accomplish is 1) search the post meta and get the post ID if there is a post meta that matches the `%custom_id%`. Else, query as normal with the value of `%custom_id%` searching for and showing the post or page.

I've thought about moving these custom id posts into a CPT, but still want the URL to be `http://mywebsi.te/kjt3l3` (the random alphanumeric assigned) and no other subfolder or slug. Which is why I was going about this approach. If there is a way to use `http://mywebsi.te/%custom_id%` with a CPT and no slug, I'm open to those suggestions.

Comment: Why not save the ID as the post slug and eliminate the need to do anything on the query side?

Comment: @Milo I think he does not need to save the post ID as the slug. He need to save the post meta value as the slug. Right Pat ?

Comment: @the_dramatist The "random alphanumeric ID", not the database ID.

Comment: @Milo I'm confused by what you mean? Each post will have a unique title, unique content, etc. I'm looking to have a sort of "anonymous" post ID for these posts. So that you can't go through and go to `/1`, `/2`, so on down the list. So my end goal is a way for the permalinks to have random alphanumerics as well as still retain normal post and page capability. So maybe CPT so long as the URL doesn't have a CPT slug?

Comment: @Milo I think I see what you mean now. Put that alphanumeric into the `post_name` field, then change permalinks to use the `Post Name` option. So far it seems to be doing the job a lot easier than I thought. Do I have it right? If so, put it into an answer and I'll accept it so long as i'm not missing anything by what you meant.